# I can't apply css for "while" looping

Tags: php, mysql, css

i want to apply css for a while looping but it returns only the first data if i use css , and without css it returns all the data normally. here is my code it's simple.

```
     $users=mysql_query("select * from users");
        while($user=mysql_fetch_array($users))
        {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='user'>";
        echo $user['pseudo'];
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: There's no css in your code.

Comment: I know !! the css was just simple i was trying to apply it on it ..
`.user
{
position:fixed;
right:500;
left:500;
top:100;
background-color:red;
}`

Comment: Do you mean you want to apply CSS to the `table`?

Comment: But there *is* a [use of the deprecated mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)...

Comment: You're using malformed HTML. Your `td` gets opened inside the `tr`, but closed after it. Also, don't open and end the `table` inside the loop, but before and after it respectively.

Comment: I don't think you can `position:fixed` a `td`.

Comment: @putvande in fact this is quite true, you cannot. It completely breaks the `display:table;` logic.

Comment: @putvande : Yes with getting all the data .. cause there is some data that desepears when applying position css i think it's behind each other .. i want to know how to use position that makes the one under the other..

Comment: do i need to use relative position ?

Comment: @putvande : THANK YOU A LOT 'relative' worked .. i forgot to try it .. and now i'm getting -5 for a noob's question ..:S

Comment: @user3787287 -6 is for not asking the question properly and not for noob's question.You should have mentioned informations like `where you want to add the css code` , `what css code you use` .

Comment: I just didn't knew this .. i'm kind of new in this website .. and i get simple errors because of non-sleeping and then when i ask every body goes to -1 without trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `position:fixed`. This tells the browser to lay all tables, one over the other, at window position `right:500; left:500; top:100;`. So, everything is there, but you tell the browser to put each new data set into a new table, and stack it in front of or behind the previous dataset (=table).

My best guess as to what you wanted to achieve is

```
$users=mysql_query("select * from users");
    echo "<table>";
    while($user=mysql_fetch_array($users))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='user'>";
    echo $user['pseudo'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @user3787287
You might want to read up on this websites rules and regulations.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users=mysql_query("select * from users");
echo "<table>";
while($user=mysql_fetch_array($users))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='user'>";
    echo $user['pseudo'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Your HTML was malformed before. The `tr` was closed, before the `td` was (`<tr><td></tr></td>`) which is invalid. Also it makes more sense to wrap the loop in the `table`, instead of declaring it in every iteration.

Comment: Sorry this was a pasting error ... but it's under ..